# How can we use video with splash screen API Android 12?

Tags: android, splash-screen, android-12

I want to use video on splash screen with using splash screen API android 12, How Can I use video as a theme?

Answer (score 0):

I think should not show Video in splash screen, you should convert it to an animation as json and use lottie to show better.

About using Splash Screen from android and above are guided in the link below:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/splash-screen/migrate

Hope the answer is useful to you

Comment: Lottie requires a separate activity but with in Splash Screen API we use the theme and do not need separate activity Then How can we use lottie animation with splash screen API ?